# Work done during phase change

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

Latent heat is needed to change a system's phase. Does the change in internal energy of the system equal only to this latent heat, or is some work done by the system as well (since the volume of the system changes)?

Comment: The latent heat is usually considered the change in enthalpy, which includes the work from volume increase.

Comment: The volume decreases when ice melts, so any work due to phase change would probably require a specific description of the material involved.